# WAMP Server phpmyadmin not working

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysqli, wamp, php

My WAMP server installation, which has been working fine up until this point, has started throwing a phpMyAdmin error.

When I go to localhost/phpmyadmin/ I get

```
phpMyAdmin - Error
The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. 
<a href="Documentation.html#faqmysql" target="documentation">
<img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Documentation" alt="Documentation" class="icon ic_b_help" /></a>
```

I have double and triple checked that extension=php_mysqli.dll is uncommented, and restarted all WAMP services several times after altering php.ini.

In addition, I have tried a fresh install of WAMP server, which produced the same result.

Comment: it looks like that this is the php_mysqli.dll itself which is not here (in bin/php/php5.x.y/ext) at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had to delete the PHPRC environment variable from a previous installation in: System Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables > System Variables